# error ebay [CDATA[ Internal error to the application ]]

Tags: java, android, ebay-api

I have to get SessionID ebay in android. I have used xml parser.

and the code is,

```
static final String url = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 100000);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity("<RuName>\"your runame\"</RuName>",HTTP.UTF_8);

//StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(),"UTF-8");
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL","673");
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", Constants.EBAY_APP_ID);
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME",Constants.EBAY_DEV_ID);
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", Constants.EBAY_CERT_ID);
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-SITEID","0");
httpPost.setHeader("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME","GetSessionID");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
//httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length","4392");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
Log.e("xml", xml);
```

But it shows response,

```
12-22 14:52:57.327: ERROR/xml(422):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eBay>
  <EBayTime>2012-12-22 07:52:57</EBayTime>
  <Errors>
   <Error>
   <Code>10007</Code>
   <ErrorClass>SystemError</ErrorClass>
   <SeverityCode>1</SeverityCode>
   <Severity>SeriousError</Severity>
   <Line>0</Line>
   <Column>0</Column>
   <ShortMessage><![CDATA[ Internal error to the application ]]></ShortMessage>
  </Error>
 </Errors>
</eBay>
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Citation from http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/Errors/ErrorMessages.htm:

> Error 10007 ("Internal error to the application") indicates an error
>   on the eBay server side, not an error in your application.

Have you tried the live site yet? The eBay sandbox sometimes is a bit buggy.

Comment: what url live site do u mean?

Comment: https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll instead of the sandbox url

Comment: I've tried this , but still same error ,

Comment: I've never worked with that API, so I got no APP-CERT for it but request-XML seems wrong. Try something like this `StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
      request.append("<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">");
      request.append(" <RuName>"+your_runame+"</RuName>");
      request.append("</GetSessionIDRequest>");
      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request.toString());` Where did you get that code from? There is a JAVA sample on the ebay site: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1661

Comment: it solved . I just write my_runame without ("") and it works :) , thanks for ur advice McIntosh

Comment: Then you just did the string concatenation wrong ;)

Comment: yup , haha , my little mistake :)